# Check if two functions are equal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, maple

I have these two functions and I wan't to check if they're the same. I know they're identical but is it possible to use maple to check it?

I already tried evalb & verify('relation') with no luck.

[image: Maple]

Comment: What is $c$? An arbitrary constant; another function?

Comment: An arbitrary constant

Comment: Try to evaluate the difference.

Comment: Fix the typo to make the expressions equal.

Comment: @mrtaurho: that doesn't matter, it is the same $c$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I had to make use of the fact that it is an arbitrary constant within my evaluation. Howsoever I would say it is at least important to explain all variables, even though they might not be of relevance, within a question.

Comment: @Combii they aren't equivalent, unless $-10+c$ is supposed to be $-10c$

Comment: @mrtaurho: no, this is pure symbolic manipulation, the meaning of the symbols doesn't matter. $c$ being $\text{ercf}(\phi)$ would make no difference.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I would say $-10c$ and $-10+c$ are not the same at all. Since you refered to a typo of the OP I would say in this case it does not matter. But for the case that he actually *meant* $-10+c$ it does matter if $c$ is arbitrary or not.

Comment: @mrtaurho: right, $-10c$ and $-10+c$ are not the same. Full stop.

Comment: I might have written something wrong. Will take a picture instead sorry. See edit with picture please

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.

$$-\frac{\ln(2)}{10} - \frac{\ln(5)}{10} = -\frac{\ln(2) + \ln(5)}{10} = -\frac{\ln(10)}{10}$$

as per the $\ln(ab)=\ln(a) + \ln(b)$, for $a,b > 0$ rule. This shows the 'initial' parts of each formula are the same.

We also have 
$$\frac{\ln\left(-\frac1{t^3+c+2t}\right)}{10} = \frac{-\ln(-(t^3+c+2t))}{10} = \frac{-\ln(-t^3-c-2t)}{10}$$

as per the similar $\ln\left(\frac1x\right) = - \ln (x)$ rule. The right side of this differs from what Maple shows only by the name of the constant: "c" vs. "_CI".

Comment: Is it possible to double check with Maple just to be sure they are the same?

Comment: I don't know anything about Maple, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Taking `_C1=c` then they are the same if `t^3+c+2*t < 0`, and differ by `-I*Pi/5` if `t^3+c+2*t > 0`.

```
restart;
raw1:=solve(-1/(10*exp(10*y))=t^3+2*t+c,y):
res1:=simplify(raw1);

                  1          1          1    /       1      \
        res1 := - -- ln(2) - -- ln(5) + -- ln|- ------------|
                  10         10         10   |   3          |
                                             \  t  + c + 2 t/

with(DEtools):
ode:=diff(y(t),t)=exp(10*y(t))*(3*t^2+2):
raw2:=simplify(rhs(dsolve(ode))):
res2:=simplify(raw2,ln);

                 1          1          1    /  3            \
       res2 := - -- ln(2) - -- ln(5) - -- ln\-t  - _C1 - 2 t/
                 10         10         10
```

Now let's simplify the difference under the assumption that the unknowns (c and t) are real. We'll substitute `_C1=c` into `res2`.

```
simplify(evalc(subs(_C1=c,res2) - res1)) assuming real;

                  1    /          / 3          \\   
                 --- I \1 + signum\t  + c + 2 t// Pi
                  10
```

Another way to see that is by re-expressing both, separately,

```
evalc(res1 + (ln(2)+ln(5))/10):
simplify(simplify(combine(%)),size) assuming real;

    1    /| 3          |\   1         1             / 3          \
  - -- ln\|t  + c + 2 t|/ + -- I Pi + -- I Pi signum\t  + c + 2 t/
    10                      20        20                          

evalc(subs(_C1=c,res2) + (ln(2)+ln(5))/10):
simplify(simplify(combine(%)),size) assuming real;

    1    /| 3          |\   1         1             / 3          \
  - -- ln\|t  + c + 2 t|/ - -- I Pi - -- I Pi signum\t  + c + 2 t/
    10                      20        20
```

We saw the `signum(t^3+c+2*t)` above. We can simplify under assumptions, separately, that `t^3+c+2*t` is positive and negative.

```
simplify(evalc(subs(_C1=c,res2) - res1)) assuming t^3+c+2*t>0;

                                1     
                               -- I Pi
                                5     

simplify(evalc(subs(_C1=c,res2) - res1)) assuming t^3+c+2*t<0;

                                  0
```

Let's check with a particular set of values, for fun,

```
simplify(eval(res1, [t=1,c=-3+exp(1)]));

                  1          1          1    1      
                - -- ln(2) - -- ln(5) - -- + -- I Pi
                  10         10         10   10     

simplify(eval(res2, [t=1,_C1=-3+exp(1)]));

                  1          1          1    1      
                - -- ln(2) - -- ln(5) - -- - -- I Pi
                  10         10         10   10     

eval(t^3+c+2*t, [t=1,c=-3+exp(1)]); # greater than zero

                               exp(1)
```

Let's take `c = -3 = _C1` and plot the real and imaginary parts of both expressions. We see a difference in the jump discontinuity of the imaginary component, at `t=1`.

```
plot([Re,Im](eval(res1, [c=-3])), t=0..2,
     thickness=3, color=[red,green],
     view=-0.5..0.5, size=[500,200]);
```

[image]

```
plot([Re,Im](eval(res2, [_C1=-3])), t=0..2,
     thickness=3, color=[red,green],
     view=-0.5..0.5, size=[500,200]);
```

[image]

We can show that the discontinuity above occurs at `t=1`, by substituting `c=-3` into a real solution of `t^3+c+2*t`.

```
map(u->(rationalize(evalc(u))),[solve(t^3+c+2*t,{t})][1]) assuming c::real:

lprint(%);

  {t = (1/6912)*((-108*c+12*(81*c^2+96)^(1/2))^(2/3)-24)
       *(-108*c+12*(81*c^2+96)^(1/2))^(2/3)*(9*c+(81*c^2+96)^(1/2))}

radnormal(eval(%,c=-3));

                               {t = 1}
```